# Compute the SUM of Time columns in the Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my attendance table, the Overtime is mentioned in the format 'hh:mm'. Its String column in the database.
Full month Overtime is entering as a single entry. So my column data is as follows

```
OVERTIME
'52:00'
'30:00'
'98:00'
'06:00'
```

Now how can get the SUM of the OverTime column.

I have tried  `SELECT SUM(OVERTIME::TIME) FROM ATTENDANCE.` Its giving me the error :

> ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "52:00"

Comment: `time` can only be used for times of the day (max. 24 hours). Try with `interval` instead.

Comment: @stickybit. I'm new with INTERVAL, Can you give an example to use Interval in this scenario, pls.

Comment: Just replace `::time` with `::interval` to cast to an `interval` rather than to a `time`. And consider changing the column's type to `interval` if possible.

Comment: @stickybit, Thanks, Let me try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the values are HH:MM, then you can use string manipulations:

```
select sum(left(overtime, 2)::numeric + right(overtime, 2)::numeric/60) as hours
```

Note that this will give the results as decimal hours.

If you want the values as an interval, you can also do that:

```
select sum( cast(overtime as interval) )
```

Note that this will give the results as days, hours, and minutes.

Answer (score 0):

The other solution didn't it in my case because I have a mix of formats i-e H:MM or HH:MM. This is what worked for me:

```
select sum(SPLIT_PART(overtime,':',1)::numeric + split_part(overtime,':',1)::numeric/60) as hours from your_table
```